# Stop a readable stream when on data finds condition

Tags: node.js, node-streams, csv-parser

I got a csv buffer that I am sending to a function.
In the buffer I got this data:

```
name,age
tom,33
pal,22
tim,60
jon,12
```

I use a node `stream` that pipes it to an object with `csv-parser` and as I go I want to see if the condition is met, if we find `tim` whos age is already above 59 I want it to stop so jon is never read, and I want this function to return a string.

```
import { Readable } from 'stream'
import csv from 'csv-parser'

export default async function (buffer) {
  Readable.from(buffer)
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (data) => {
      if (data.age > 59)
       return 'stop'
    })
}
```

This only works if I push it to an array, read the entire file and then after on end I return something.

I tried `createReadStream` but does not work with the buffer and I get and error `ENAMETOOLONG:`, with stream it works well but cannot stop `on.('data')`

Comment: You can destroy your readable: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_destroy_error

Comment: It does not work, I get `Readable.destroy()` is not a function